# PSD's in Themes on sites like Themeforest and more

Tags: html, themes

I'm trying to figure out why sites like Themeforest requires you to design a PSD template of an HTML or even Wordpress Template that you're designing.

Yes sure it might be for the odd-one-out that may want to design their site completely as a jpeg. (That's my only thinking.)

Wouldn't it be better if they wouldn't require PSD's and actually have the developer spend more time on the documentation or even code of the site?

I can not understand why they would, for example "brag" that they're including 24 PSD's with the site template.

Can somebody help me figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including PSD's can **help developers understand the individual elements** of the site, how and why they were designed and give them an idea of the colour values (such as #HEX) and styles applied to an individual element.

They are also handy to scale or save images from that were **created as vector shapes**. JPG's don't give you that type of flexibility as the image is flattened and compressed when being saved.

Lastly, if you are buying a design, you might want to build on it to suit your personal use. Having access to the PSD file will let you quickly edit what's already been done (i.e changing colours, type, images) instead of applying it over the top of a JPG.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Solid answer, especially that last paragraph. This probably stems from the common perception that all good-looking websites are designed before they are built. Having the resources (PSD files) for the site, saves buyers a fair amount of time, and possibly money in case they have to hire a designer to do it for them.

Comment: So it is basically also if you want to prototype faster in PSD etc etc. Okay, I see, thank you.